# String resource ID #0x0 in DbxAccountManager.getInstance

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I am trying to link my application with dropbox, but I have this error:

```
fatal error : String resource ID #0x0 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0

in the line : DbxAccountManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), appKey, appSecret);
```

When I create a new project and try to link it works fine, but when I include it on my project it fails.

I tried cleaning my project and creating a new one but with no use. Any hints please what may be the problem?

note -> appKey and appSecret are final static strings, am not calling it from Resources.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing android:label="my app name" to android:label="@string/app_name" solved the problem.